# Loading application.properties from another Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I have three Spring Boot projects.  Project A `Autowires` a bean from Project B.  That bean in Project B relies on properties from the `application.properties` in Project C.  Project B will always be run with Project C.  However, there are times when Project A will be run standalone.

Project A `build.gradle.kts`

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":project-b"))
```

Rather than duplicate the properties in Project A's `application.properties`, is there a way to load, or reference, the `application.properties` from Project C in Project A without it running?

I've tried to use adding a dependency to Project C and also `@PropertySource` in Project A `@Configuration` file, but no luck:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/meanwhile/in/hell/project-c/src/main/resources/application.properties")
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/meanwhile/in/hell/project-c/src/main/resources/application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Centralized Configuration(Spring Cloud Config Server), the application property file is saved in git(remote or local) the server will be sync the git and you can consume the application files by running the server. for reference https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/